# java: Map<String, List<Interface>> can not apply to Map<String, List<Implementation>>

Tags: java, oop, generic-programming

I met one puzzle about java generics which I never met before and post out here, hope you could have one check at it.
Here the whole code:

```
public class FakeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<FakeConcretClassA> concretFakes = new ArrayList<>();
        concretFakes.add(new FakeConcretClassA());

        Map<String, List<FakeConcretClassA>> fakemap = new HashMap<>();
        fakemap.put("key1", concretFakes);


        printFakeVals(concretFakes);
        priFakeMap(fakemap);

    }

    public static void priFakeMap(Map<String, List<? extends FakeInterface>> 
fakemap)
    {
        fakemap.forEach((genre, fakes) -> {
            fakes.forEach(fake -> System.out.println(fake.fakeVal()));
        });
    }

    public static void printFakeVals(List<? extends FakeInterface> fakes)
    {
        fakes.forEach(fake -> System.out.println(fake.fakeVal()));;
    }
}
```

The **FakeInterface** is just one simple interface which requires one method that return hardcoded value, and **FakeConcretClassA** return '111' for implementation. What is strange here is that the **printFakeVals(concretFakes);** could pass java compile but the **priFakeMap(fakemap);** could not. 
Per my understanding, **FakeConcretClassA** implements **FakeInterface** so I could pass **list of FakeConcretClassA** as param to method which receives **list of objs which implements FakeInterface**.  But why when wrapped into the map and the compile would fail?